# Inheritance - Tricky OOP Concepts

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

What would be the right answer to following?

[image]Please refer the above figure for this question.Each class in the above figure contains an instance constructor and static constructor. B class is derived from the A class. Now coming to question, what will be the sequence of the constructors called among 1, 2, 3, and 4 in each of the following cases.

A a = new A();

B b = new A();

A c = new B();

B d = new B();

Referring the above figure, Method() from which class will be called in case of method overloading and method hiding respectively for the below cases. The methods are numbered as 5 and 6

a.Method();

b.Method();

c.Method();

d.Method();

Comment: Downvote reason: Why don't you test yourself? Don't you know there are online c# compilers on the internet?

Comment: Exactly, breakpoint breakpoint breakpoint

Comment: Downvote: Reads like a assignment given on the first Workshop of an OOP CompSci course >.>

Comment: BTW, `B b = new A();` is a compiler error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually easy to test

However

[Static Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors)

> A static constructor is used to initialize any static data, or to
>   perform a particular action that needs to be performed once only. It
>   is called automatically before the first instance is created or any
>   static members are referenced.

Static constructor is called when the class is accessed the first time. So the static constructor of B will be called first if you access the B, static constructor of A is not called until you use the A. If you use A first, then static constructor of A is called first and other way around.

The instance constructor will get called when the class is initialized